# How do I setup Eclipse to disable wide-character display?

Tags: eclipse

This issue happens on HD screens with newer version of Eclipse.
The character rendering is special and typical of HD with very wide characters that may be considered more beautiful but take too much space on screen, especially when doing code comparisons on an already reduced portion of screen.

There is an icon button called "Toggle Block Selection Mode (Alt + Shift + A)" that enables column mode editing. In my case that button changes how characters are rendered on my screen, and make them look more narrow, and like the display used to be before "HD". Normally, this button is not supposed to change anything to how the text is rendered. On other computers, especially at my workplace, it does not change anything, as expected.

[image: Toggle Block Selection Mode (Alt + Shift + A)]

Is there a way I can setup Eclipse or Windows to disable that wide-character display ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 36.52 When I switch to Block (Column) Selection mode the font changes Please make sure the Text Font and the Text Editor Block Selection
> Font are the same:
>
> go to General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts
>
> in the list on the right, under the Basic category you should see
>
> Text Font
>
> Text Editor Block Selection Font
>
> The fonts should be the same

https://dvteclipse.com/documentation/e/When_I_switch_to_Block_.28Column.29_Selection_mode_the_font_changes.html

In my case the difference is probably "Courrier New" vs "Consolas" font.

But how that configuration mess was introduced is still a mystery.